# outlook 2007 mail span not displayed in same line

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

**My code is:**

```
    <span style="text-align:center; width:80px; display:inline-block;">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">
   img here
    <span style="font-size: 13px; color: #301985; display:block; top:5px; position:relative;">content</span>
    </a>
    </span>
    <span style="text-align:center; width:80px; display:inline-block;">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">
    img here
    <span style="font-size: 13px; color: #301985; display:block; top:5px; position:relative;">content</span>
    </a>
    </span>
```

**Problem is:**

It is working good in all mail. In outlook 2007 it displayed like this image.

[image]

I want content is displayed the below the image. But it is not working in outlook 2007.

I found this url https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Display, float property are not working on outlook 2007. Any other solution to acheive my design?

Answer (score 1):

use `<div>` in place of `<span>` I hope it will help...

Comment: thn remove all display css also put "display:block" in img tags

Comment: if i remove all display span not displayed in same line.

Comment: ok please add display:block in img tag..

or 

you have to use <tr> <td> in place of <span> than use display:block

Comment: I added display block to all img tag. But not use.